# What is the relation between expected average reward and single step mean reward for a non-stationary MDP policy?

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning

The expected average reward for a policy $\pi$ is:
$$ \rho_\pi  = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty } \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} r_t$$
where $r_t$ is the reward obtained at time $t$ following policy $\pi$.

For a stationary policy $\pi$,
$$
\rho_\pi + \lambda_\pi(s) = \bar{r}(s, \pi(s)) + \sum_{s'} p(s'|s,a) \cdot \lambda_\pi(s')
$$
where $\bar{r}(s,a)$ and $p(\cdot|s,a)$ are the mean rewards and transition probabilities of the MDP respectively and $\lambda_\pi$ is the bias vector of $\pi$.

Does a similar relation exist for a non-stationary policy?

Edit- Reference for bias vector: The Handbook of Markov Decision Processes [1](http://webee.technion.ac.il/~adam/MDPHandBook/index.html) defines bias of a stationary deterministic policy as follows:

$\lambda_\pi(s) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[\bar{r}(s_n, \pi(s_n)) - \rho_\pi | s_0 = s]$

where n indicates the current time step and $s_n$ indicates the state at time step $n$ after following policy $\pi$ starting from the initial state $s_0 = s$

Comment: Is the non-stationary policy following a specific formula or have any constraints applied to how it can evolve over time?

Comment: Hi @NeilSlater, no but if having any constraints on the non-stationarity leads to a relation between average reward and single step mean reward, then the constraints could be accommodated.

Comment: The Handbook of Markov Decision Processes [1] defines bias of a stationary deterministic policy as follows:

$\lambda(s, \pi) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} E[\bar{r}(s_n, \pi(s_n)) - \rho_\pi]$   [1]: http://webee.technion.ac.il/~adam/MDPHandBook/index.html

Comment: n indicates the current time step. $s_n$ indicates the state at time step $n$ after following policy $\pi$ starting from the initial state $s_0 = s$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it is clearer to me now.